# PHP Upload Progress Status

Tags: php, jquery, upload, progress-bar

I need to show upload status (Total size, curent uploaded size and upload speed) But every script need library and I don'T know how it work (I use XAMPP under Windows)... I have only APC Lib.

I tried FancyUpload, but even in the demo I got this error :
Error caused a send or load operation to fail (Error #2038)
And I tried SWFUpload, but get the same message.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: SWFUpload needs a PHP script to send the upload to.  Can you show us yours?

Comment: I don't have PHP code localy. I tested it online and for any upload script using progress bar I get IO error... :(

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), easy to use and allot of examples.
And it has a progress bar that you wanted, and it shows the speed and how many bytes that have been uploaded.
Easy to configure.

jQuery 1.3.2+ is required for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but I get IO Error when uploading an image. :S

Answer (score 0):

hmm, that's wierd, but here is my settings:

```
'uploader': '/_PATH_TO_YOUR_/uploader.swf', // Path to uploader.swf
'cancelImg': '/_PATH_TO_YOUR_/cancel.png', // Path to any cancel image
'script': '/_PATH_TO_YOUR_/upload.php', // Path to your upload script, you may change this to something else, depends on what your server is running
'folder': '/uploaded/',  // Your upload filder
//'fileDesc': 'Images Only (*.PNG, *.JPG, *.JPEG, *.GIF)', // Use this if you want to allow only image uploads, is shown when you press the Browse button in side the file types box
//'fileExt': '*.png, *.jpg, *.gif, *.jpeg', // Allowed file extensions
'sizeLimit': 52428800, // Max file size
'simUploadLimit': 1, // Only 1 upload at the same time, 0 = unlimited uploads at the same time
'multi': true, // Allows multi-upload, you can select more then 1 file/image
'buttonText': 'Select Files', // This I don't know if it works
'checkScript': '/source/interface/addons/uploadify/check.php', // Path to your upload check script
'displayData': 'speed', // What to display when you start the upload
'buttonText': 'Browse', // The browse button, .swf file
```

If you could, you can post the JavaScript that you have so far, so I can help you :)

Comment: Hi Endre and sorry for the delay I was very busy, I appreciate your help :). Actually, I tried the demo that come with the script and I got this error... Even on the official website on the demo page...

Comment: Oh wait, sorry I think it's my Firefox since i just tried it in IE8 and it work beautifully :S So I'll try to uninstall and reinstall Firefox... I'll give updates as soon as I have results.

Comment: Okay, everything is working fine except one thing... the file is not uploaded on the server (localhost), I uploaded a huge file (3 Gb) and my computer's cpu go above 75%, but its not on localhost... I can post a copy of my uploadify.php... Have an idea?

Comment: sorry for not answering, been on vacation ;) have you loaded upliadify.js?... here is my setup, http://bithack.org/static/revision/custom_uploadify_demo.txt .... the .php files are untouched, and you might need to update jGrowl to the newest release, I don't remember...